# Gráfico de barras no ggplot no r

Tags: r, ggplot2

A base de dados que estou lendo é a seguinte:

```
 Trimestre   PIB
 1º T 2018  0.005
 2º T 2018  0.000
 3º T 2018  0.005
 4º T 2018  0.001
 1º T 2019 -0.001
 2º T 2019  0.004
```

Fiz um plot de barras com o seguinte código:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(dados, aes(x=Trimestre, y=PIB)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Trimestre), stat="identity") + 
  theme_minimal()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+
  geom_label(aes(label = percent(PIB)),
             position = position_dodge(0.9), vjust=0.5, size=3.5,
             hjust = 0.5)
```

E ele me retornou a figura abaixo.

A 1º dúvida é: Como deixar o eixo x, onde aparecem os Trimestres, de forma ordenada? Ex: 1ºTrimestre 2018, 2ºTrimestre de 2018, 3ºTrimestre 2018...

A 2º dúvida é: Como alterar o percentual para que ele leia somente com uma casa decimal depois da vírgula?

Agradeço!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Quanto à primeira pergunta, basta transformar `Trimestre` em vetor de classe `"factor"` com os níveis (`levels`) na ordem pretendida.

Quanto à segunta pergunta, a função `percent` tem um argumento `accuracy` que substitui o anterior `digits`. Este argumento deve ser `0.1` para arredondar os números para uma só casa decimal.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

dados$Trimestre <- factor(dados$Trimestre, levels = unique(dados$Trimestre))

ggplot(dados, aes(x = Trimestre, y = PIB)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Trimestre), stat = "identity") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  geom_label(aes(label = percent(PIB, accuracy = 0.1)),
             position = position_dodge(0.9), 
             vjust = 0.5, size = 3.5, hjust = 0.5)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dados em formato `dput`.**

```
dados <-
structure(list(Trimestre = c("1º T 2018", "2º T 2018", 
"3º T 2018", "4º T 2018", "1º T 2019", "2º T 2019"), 
PIB = c(0.005, 0, 0.005, 0.001, -0.001, 0.004)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Ótimo! Deu certinho! Muito obrigada!

Comment: Você sabe como fazer a mesma ideia de ordenar o eixo y, mas agora com dados anuais e mensais, para um gráfico de linhas também, não só de barras?

Comment: @LetíciaMarrara Só vendo os dados...